# Are DDR3 SDRAM's DQL and DQU pins different?

Tags: soc, ddr3

Obviously they are, but I am using the Allwinner A20 and alliance memories AS4C128M16D3B-12BCN 2GB, it has DQU1,2,3,4 etc pins, but the Allwinner A20 does not, it only has the DQL, no DQU.  This memory is fully supported by the Soc, but for some reason appears to be missing pins? Am I correct in thinking that DQU is just a continuation of DQL? from what the data sheet says, they are both data strobes. Any help appreciated as I am well and truly confused.

Comment: I think that it is a bit confusing

Are you talking about data bits (DQ) or about mask bits (DMU and DML?)

Comment: sorry, on the ram component there are, pins labeled, DQLU and DQU. but I cannot find the corresponding pins for the latter on the SOC.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop your efforts only because a minor difference in the names. OK, so Alliance calls its data pins DQU and DQL, and AllWinner calls them SDQ. But from analyzing the datasheet it should be obvious for you that they are all data pins, 8 DQU and 8 DQL for the memory, 32 SDQ for the processor. Similarly you can solve the case for all the pins, not by their names, but by their functionality. If still in doubt, try to find a reference design for the processor (and the memory).

Comment: Okay, so they can all be connected to SDQ?

Comment: Yes you can  ....